# .map function's index with methods inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

my code gives me following error:

```
Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `classroom-1278238`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
```

I have these 2 parts where I use .map method. I tried to put my code between `<span key={index}></span>` and define 'index' inside map, but React JS Typescript doesn't accept that.

```
classroomFeatures.map((classroom_features: Types.ISelectOption) => {
                                        return (
                                          <React.Fragment key={'classroom_features-' + classroom_features.value}>
                                            <button className="multiple-info-tag small-tag text-capitalize">
                                              {classroom_features.label}
                                            </button>
                                            <br />
                                          </React.Fragment>
                                        );
                                      })
```

> 

```
item.classroomInfo.feature_codes.map((featureCode: string) => {
                          const feature = ClassroomFeatureOptions.find(
                            (item: Types.ISelectOption) => item.value && item.value === featureCode
                          );
                          if (feature) {
                            classroomFeatures.push(feature);
                          }
                        });
```

Comment: What properties you have in `classroom_features ` object?

Comment: @SajibKhan `classroom_features` is an interface, contains `label` and `value`.

Comment: ok so I guess either `label` or, `value` is not unique! Could you try something like: `key={Date.now()}` ?

Comment: I just tried it, it gives me the same error, but now same key is this Date.now value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `classroom-1278238`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Here the `key` should be unique. Generate a unique value for key:

```
key={'_'  +  Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)}
```